# How to wire up a BNC Connector in Eagle

Tags: connector, eaglecad, bnc

Good day! I am in the process of adding some right angle bnc female connectors onto my PCB but I have no idea how to decipher the schematic file and have no idea which pins connect with what. The BNC connector I am using is the 1-1337543-0 from TE Connectivity: https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-1337543-0/A97553-ND/1755940.

[image]

Here is the footprint and symbol in eagle. Questions: 
1. What is the SHIELD?
2. What is P1*2?
3. Where does the signal connect?
4. Where does ground connect?

Thank you!

Comment: `P1*2` means `2` pins including `P1`. They are two pins for mechanical stability.

Answer (score 3):

The pin in the middle is the hot conductor (middle of the coax). The other small pin goes to the shield of the coax, and the two big holes are for mechanical stability, so connect pin 1 to hot/signal, everything else to GND.

Check later in layout editor that pin 1 is really the one closest to the center.